# php count not working properly in my array

Tags: php, arrays

i print php array when it's empty it print 1

```
$addresses = $user->myFunction();
print_r(count($addresses['my_test']));
Array
(
    [my_test] => Array
        (
            [test] => test
            [test1] => test1
        )

)
```

it print 2

when i print this

```
Array
(
    [my_test] => Array
        (
            [] => 
        )

)
```

i got 1

i don't know what is the problem here

How to print exact value of this?

Comment: you still have one empty array inside, nothing is wrong in the count result

Comment: Check your `$user->myFunction()` you may not return what you think it should. And you can always call `array_filter` to avoid empty element and then count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array count all element including **empty ones**. Your output is correct as you second array has 1 element.

Consider use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to avoid them.

Example:

```
$a = array("" => "");
echo count($a). PHP_EOL; // echo 1
$a = array_filter($a);
echo count($a). PHP_EOL; // echo 0
```

In you case:

```
 print_r(count(array_filter($addresses['my_test'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [my_test] => Array
        (
            [test] => test
            [test1] => test1
        )

)
print_r(count($addresses['my_test'])); // it will show 2 cause you have 2 values inside my_test key.

print_r(count($addresses)); // it will show 1 cause you have one value inside main array

Array
(
    [my_test] => Array
        (
            [] => 
        )

)

print_r(count($addresses['my_test'])); // it will show 0 because you have 0 values inside my_test key.

print_r(count($addresses)); //it will show 1 because you have one value my_test inside your main array.
```

Hope it helps you clarify count function.